# How can a RNN with 256 cells accept a input of any size?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

I built a 3 layered RNN model with 256 cells each using torch. Input feature size is set to 40. Below give a basic Idea on the model.

```
 lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=40,
                        hidden_size=256, 
                        num_layers=3, 
                        batch_first=True)
 self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features=256, 
                            out_features=256)
 self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
```

[image]

Now after getting an Idea on how it looks, how can it accept an input of any size of form (x, 40) say (160, 40). It should only be able to accept of size (256, 40). If not

**What happens after time step 160?** Do the remaining cells take output of previous cell to be its input. Like below[image]

Or **is the input mapped from (160, 40) to (256, 60)** using some Neural Network before giving it to the RNN.